# Must declare the scalar variable "@EmailID"

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error. I have declared EmailID in my application code. Not sure what this error exactly asking me to do!

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Must declare the scalar variable "@EmailID".

The error exception is thrown on this line of code: var em = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

```
public void UpdateEmailDB(ref Email email)
    {
        string UpdateTelefon = @"UPDATE telfeon
                    SET EmailAddress  = @email, PersonID = @PersonId
                    WHERE EmailID = @EmailID";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(UpdateTelefon, OpenConnection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.EmailAddress);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonId", email.PersonID);

            var em = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailID",...);`? Also, required reading: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I thought it wasn't necessary to be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually adding a value to your @EmailId parameter.  You do it to @email and @PersonId, you are missing @EmailId.

Comment: Thanks. I did add it. It fixed that error, but thrown another mystical error at the same line of code. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'telfeon'.'

Comment: @user10489212 I am guessing telfeon is the name of the table you are trying to update?  Make sure you are spelling it right and you are connecting to the correct DB.

Comment: Double check the table name.   Maybe add schema (xxx.telfeon).

Comment: I spotted the error. I should never do copy paste. The error came as I have copied from the UpdateTelefon() :(

Comment: .. but now it says : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot update identity column 'EmailID'.'

Comment: @user10489212 if your column EmailID has an identity property, it is an auto-generated self-increment column which you don't need to insert or update anything on. SQL Server will do this for you... just skip this column insert